# Android: Intent that is fired by AlarmManager is not containing my Flags

Tags: android, android-intent, flags, android-pendingintent

When my App crashes I create an Intent with a FLAG_CRASH.
I call PendingIntent.getActivity with that Intent, and hand the resulting PendingIntent over to AlarmManager.

After 1 Second it restarts my App. Yet on older API Levels (< 9) getFlags on the Intent always returns 0. API Level 15 returns my Flags. Any Idea why? Did some default behavior change happen between the Versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a broadcast receiver that I can fire an own distinct intent via pending intent. That broadcast receiver builds another intent for the activity and puts an extra into it for signaling the crash. In the Activty I have a handler method that I call from both onNewIntent and onCreate, the handler creates the error popup and resets the extra.